# How can I set up react native maps to use custom markers by calling the file names?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, jsx, react-native-maps

I am trying to replace `'GREEN'` in my image path with a string from my database. I bring in a string on the line above (`title={listing.title}`) but am unsure what syntax to use to bring in another string (in this case `{listing.pin}`) to replace `'GREEN'`.

What is the proper syntax here?

```
const markerArr = data.map((listing, index) => (
    <Marker
      key={index}
      title={listing.title}
      image={require('../../../assets/pins/PIN' + 'GREEN' + '.png')}
      // description={listing.description}
      onCalloutPress={() => {
        onPressListingItem(listing);
      }}
      coordinate={{
        latitude: listing.latitude,
        longitude: listing.longitude,
      }}
    />
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
const green = listing.title;
const blue = listing.pin;
const markerArr = data.map((listing, index) => (
  <View>
    <Marker
      key={index}
      title={green}
      image={require(`../../../assets/pins/PIN${green.toString().toUpperCase()}.png`)}
      // description={listing.description}
      onCalloutPress={() => {
        onPressListingItem(listing);
      }}
      coordinate={{
        latitude: listing.latitude,
        longitude: listing.longitude,
      }}
    />
    <Marker
      key={index}
      title={blue}
      image={require(`../../../assets/pins/PIN${blue.toString().toUpperCase()}.png`)}
      // description={listing.description}
      onCalloutPress={() => {
        onPressListingItem(listing);
      }}
      coordinate={{
        latitude: listing.latitude,
        longitude: listing.longitude,
      }}
    />
  </View>
));
```

I am assuming `listing.title === "Green"` and `listing.pin === "Blue"` just as an example. If there is a logical relationship as to when to use `listing.title` and `listing.pin` then you can want to use only one variable instead of two (green & blue) and then make use of a ternary operator like `const something = somelogic is true ? listing.title : listing.pin`